# excel remove rows with same data

Tags: excel

I have one excel document with two columns of data.
First column with 19k rows of data and second column with 2k rows of data.
All of the data in the 2nd column exists in the 1st column. 
I want to delete all the rows in the 1st column which have the data from the 2nd column. 
Is there a way how to do that?>
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: Is there a large amount of distinct values in the second column?  For example, are we talking 4, 40, 400, or 4000 distinct second column values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work through column A and delete any row that has a value that appears in any row in column B. It assume both column A and B values start in row 1:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

    Dim colB As Variant, iRow As Long
    colB = Range("B1:B2000") //Add you reference for column B

    For iRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 1), colB, 0)) Then
            Cells(iRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next iRow  

End Sub
```

Comment: As you have it, you are changing the list you check the values in Column A against by deleting values from Column B as well.  I think @Laziale really wants the cells in Column A deleted (preserving Column B), not entire rows.

Comment: @Excelllll - whilst the OP does not explicitly state that, if that is the case, it is easily fixed by removing `EntireRow`. Let see if the OP comes back with some comments of his own.

Comment: I was trying to point out that your logic won't get the job done in some cases. For instance, if Column A contains {a,b,c,d,e,f}, and Column B contains {f,e,d,c,b,a}, all rows should be deleted. However, your code will leave the top 3 rows.

Comment: @Excellll - you are correct. I have updated the code to read column B in as an array so that the references are static. Checked your example and it now removes all rows. Tnanks much.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably much easier to do it with [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep):

Export each column to a file and do a "grep -v". Here is an example:

```
$ cat col1.txt 
A
B
C
D
$ cat col2.txt 
B
D
$ grep -v -f col2.txt col1.txt 
A
C
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA is probably the easiest way to do this.  Try the following macro.  It will delete all cells in Column A that match any values in Column B.  If you need to do this for other columns, just adjust the code to match the design of your workbook.

```
Sub removematches()

Dim firstcolumn() As Variant
Dim colA As Range
Dim colB As Range
Dim i As Long, del As Long

'This will set the ranges to look in.  Note that this will only work for data with no blank cells.  If you have blank cells, you can change these Set statements to the following:
' Set colA = Range("A1:A100") if you have 100 rows you want to look at.
Set colA = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set colB = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))

firstcolumn = colA

ReDim Preserve firstcolumn(1 To UBound(firstcolumn), 1 To 2) As Variant
i = 1
del = 0

Do While i <= UBound(firstcolumn)
    firstcolumn(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(colB, firstcolumn(i, 1))
    If firstcolumn(i, 2) > 0 Then
        Range("A1").Offset(i - del - 1, 0).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        del = del + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```